# Extract WORLDCLIM data using R for a single country

Tags: r, extract

I want to extract world climate data for minimum and maximum temperature for only one country India using R and save it as a data set (to use with my own data-set that contains crop yields at the district level).
I have gone through several posts and can see that this can be done easily in R, however the posts that I have tried to follow are a bit different in terms of the commands or sequences and I am getting confused.
(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/259478/worldclim-data-na-for-my-coordinates, https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/227585/using-r-to-extract-data-from-worldclim

What I have tried to use is as follows.

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
r<- getData('CMIP5', var='tmin', res=10, rcp=45, model='HE', year=70)
r <- r[[c(1,12)]]
values <- extract(r,points)
df <- cbind.data.frame(coordinates(points),values)
head(df)
```

However, I can run only the first two lines and the line values

```
<- extract(r,points) gives the error Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extract’ for signature ‘"RasterStack", "function"’
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where is your `points` object? Please provide that in the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not sure what I am supposed to put in the points object. the above lines are the only code line that i have executed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should have a file containing latitude and longitude in two columns for which you want to extract the bioclimatic variables.

Comment: once again thank you for your answer. I have a file containing the GIS data for all districts in India. Should the latitudes be the boundaries of all Indian districts or the centroids of these district?

Comment: By GIS data, do you want to mean shapefile? If you are having shapefile then you can extract data in two ways: 1. Using the centroids of the districts and 2. Using zonal statistics i.e. average value for the whole area under the district.

Comment: Yes I have shape files at the district level containing the Centroids and another containing the coordinates for the district boundaries. what would be the steps to extract the data using the centroids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for it

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
library(sf)

r<- getData('CMIP5', var='tmin', res=10, rcp=45, model='HE', year=70)

#Using Zonal statistics
poly <- shapefile("Provide_your_drive_name" e.g. "F:\\Kriging in R\\India Shape files\\2011_Dist.shp")
plot(poly)

#This will take considerable time
ex <- extract(r, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE) 

write.csv(cbind(poly$DISTRICT,ex),"Worldclim.csv", row.names = F)

# using centroids
nc <- st_read(dsn="Provide_your_drive_name" e.g. "F:\\Kriging in R\\India Shape files", layer="2011_Dist")
# just view the attributes & first 6 attribute values of the data
head(nc)
sp_cent <- gCentroid(as(nc, "Spatial"), byid = TRUE)
values <- extract(r,sp_cent)

write.csv(cbind(as.data.frame(nc$DISTRICT),as.data.frame(values)),"Worldclim_centroids.csv", row.names = F)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am going to try this now.

Comment: I run the code, but on the fifth & sixth line it gives the errors
**ex <- extract(r, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE) Warning message:In .local(x, y, ...) :  "fun" was changed to "mean"; other functions cannot be used when "weights=TRUE" ** and the sixth line the error

write.csv(cbind(poly$NAME_2,ex),"Worldclim.csv", row.names = F)
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 594**

Comment: You need not to worry about the Warning message, it is saying that it can only implement `mean` function. Regarding the 2nd error can you show me the output of `head(nc@data)`. Your operation is already done. You can see it by calling  `ex `.

Comment: Yes sir when I call the eg command I see that the operation is dome

When I do **head(nc@data)** I get the following 

**> head(nc@data)
Error in head(nc@data) : object 'nc' not found**

Comment: Are you getting the plot from `plot(poly)`? If not then you are not able to read in the shape file properly.

Comment: Yes the plot is appearing as soon as I execute **plot(poly)**

Comment: Sir it is as below:

write.csv(cbind(poly$NAME_2,ex),"Worldclim.csv", row.names = F)
**Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 594**
head(poly@data) gives me the first five lines of the data **              ST_NM ST_CEN_CD DT_CEN_CD  DISTRICT
0           Gujarat        24        15     Anand
1    Andhra Pradesh        28        22 Anantapur
2 Jammu and Kashmir        01        06  Anantnag
3            Orissa        21        15    Anugul
4             Bihar        10        07    Araria

Comment: I want to see the output of that because `poly$NAME_2` is coming from that shape file. Which column of the head of poly file contains the district names? You have to use that in place of `NAME_2`

Comment: Column 4 contains the name of the districts. I executed **write.csv(cbind(poly$NAME_4,ex),"Worldclim.csv", row.names = F)**
I got the same error **Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 594**

Comment: Use `poly$DISTRICT`. If it works don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Hi sir I replaced poly$NAME_2 with poly$DISTRICT and it worked. I was able to import the data in csv format.
Sir above you mention that data can be extracted in two ways **1** Using the centroids of the districts and **2** Using zonal statistics i.e. average value for the whole area under the district.
The method I just completed is option 1 from above?

Comment: I have clearly written in my code #using zonal statistics and #using centroids. Please accept the answer by clicking the √ below the upvote and down vote symbol.

Comment: Just completed it sir. Thank you for your help.

Comment: (I am not sure whether to follow on this thread or start a new question)
The first time I executed the above code I was able  to import the TMIN data for all 12 months.
However now when I execute it I only get three variables: DISTRICT name, TMIN for month 1 and TMIN for month 12.
I see that when I execute **ex <- extract(r, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE)** it extracts only 3 variables not 13 (12 months + I district name).
(I can see that the data for all the 12 months is downloaded in the default folder).