# Extracting WorldClim data in R but some months are missing

Tags: r, extract

I had a question regarding extracting WorldClim data in R and received excellent help ([Extract WORLDCLIM data using R for a single country](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60316356/extract-worldclim-data-using-r-for-a-single-country/60317798?noredirect=1#comment106726123_60317798))

The solution works fine but I am now facing a separate issue.

I execute the following code to extract and save the WorldClim monthly data for minimum temperature in .cvs format

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)
library(rgdal)
r<- getData('CMIP5', var='tmin', res=10, rcp=45, model='HE', year=70)
r <- r[[c(1,12)]]
poly <- shapefile("C:/Users/pc5/Desktop/r1//2011_Dist.shp")
plot(poly)
pr <- extract(r, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE) 
write.csv(cbind(poly$DISTRICT,ex),"Worldclim.csv", row.names = F)
```

However when I extract and save the data I only get three variables: DISTRICT name, TMIN for month 1 and TMIN for month 12. 
I see that when I run the code

```
ex <- extract(r, poly, fun='mean', na.rm=TRUE, df=TRUE, weights = TRUE)
```

it extracts only 3 variables not 13 (12 months + I district name) though I can see that the data for all the 12 months is downloaded in the default folder in Geotiff format. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use `na.rm=TRUE`, so if there are missing data they will be skipped, try without this option to see if you get `no data` for some months, which would mean that unfortunately for you data do not exist for some months (but at least explain why you get nothing)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried it but got the same result.

I did not mention in the above post that the first time I ran the above code I was able to save the entire data in .cvs format. However the second time I tried I faced the above problem.

Comment: What happens if you omit this line: `r <- r[[c(1,12)]]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the code without `r <- r[[c(1,12)]]`, you will give desired the results.  `r <- r[[c(1,12)]]` part of code sunsetting only 1 and 12 month from raster stack of 12 months data. You can ascertain that by the following code

```
r<- getData('CMIP5', var='tmin', res=10, rcp=45, model='HE', year=70)
r #will show you dimensions  : 900, 2160, 1944000, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
r1 <- r[[c(1,12)]]
r1 #will show you dimensions  : 900, 2160, 1944000, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
plot(r) #Plot of all the 12 months
plot(r1) #Plot of only 1 and 12 month
```

I have edited my pervious answer also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I deleted the line and was able to save data for all 12 months. Is there any way to loop this command so that I can extract data for minimum and maximum temperature and save it without running this command repeatedly?
For example
`r<- getData('CMIP5', var='tmin', res=10, rcp=45, model='HE', year=70)`
`r<- getData('CMIP5', var='tman', res=10, rcp=45, model='HE', year=70)`

Comment: Also is there anything that I need to change for the alternative centroid method. Because when I run it I get the following error
`# using centroids
nc <- readOGR(dsn="C:\\Users\\pc5\\Desktop\\R\\2011_Dist.shp", layer="india70again")
# view the attributes & first 6 attribute values of the data
head(nc@data)
sp_cent <- gCentroid(as(nc, "Spatial"), byid = TRUE)
Error in TopologyFunc(spgeom, id, byid, "rgeos_getcentroid") : 
  rgeos_convert_R2geos: invalid R class Spatial, unable to convert`

Comment: For the centroid option the code works till I execute **
sp_cent <- gCentroid(as(nc, "Spatial"), byid = TRUE)** then I get the error
**Error in TopologyFunc(spgeom, id, byid, "rgeos_getcentroid") : 
  rgeos_convert_R2geos: invalid R class Spatial, unable to convert**

Comment: Try the answer to your previous question. I have used `sf` library now to read in the shapefile and the error does not appear.

Comment: I was able to extract using the Centroid method. It works.